# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Unity

Tags: c#, exception, unity-game-engine, null, gameobject

Hey guys so I have am a new programmer. For the school's intake, i have to make a unity game. So I decided to make a scrolling shooter. I have two scripts one on a game object and the other on a UI element. I want to change the score in the UI element from the game object when it is destroyed. But I keep getting this error code whenever I kill the object:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
EnemyController.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/EnemyController.cs:22)

The enemyController is a prefab and will be spawning multiple.
This is the offending code:

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour {

public ScoreUi scoreUi;

void Update(){
        if (health <= 0) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
            scoreUi.score++;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the UI script
Line 22 is a UI.Text object that is throwing the NULL exception marked by !!!.

```
public class ScoreUi : MonoBehaviour {


    static int score = 0;
    public Text Score;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    //This is line 22.
!!!    Score.text = "Score: " + score.ToString ();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which line is line 22?

Comment: You need to drag the GameObject `ScoreUi` script is attached to to the `scoreUi` variable slot in the `EnemyController` script. You can also use GetComponent to do that.

Comment: If you decide to do it with script, add this to the `EnemyController` script: `void Start(){scoreUi = GameObject.Find("Name Of Object ScoreUi Is Attached To").GetComponent<ScoreUi>( );}`